# Python: Dynamically define a function with arguments coming from a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, function, dynamic

I have the following situation.
A user passes me a list of strings, lets say:

`params = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

I now need to automatically define a function, ley's say:

`my_fun(a, b, c)`

which, once it's defined with the correct arguments, will be called correctly downstream.

It is important that the arguments in the function are in fact named.

The only path forward I see is to use `eval()` with a manually constructed string that defines a function, making use of the `params` list in the process.

As far as I am aware, this is not good style though.

I would greatly appreciate a suggestion on how to proceed in this case.

Comment: What's your use case?  Show us an example.  Constructing code on the fly has always been horrible practice.  How is the "user" going to pass you a list of strings?  Why can't you just pass in a dictionary?  Honestly, if you don't know the parameters at compile time, how can you possible code the function?

Comment: yeah. give a proper use case with sample inputs and sample outputs